# String c++ manipulation

Tags: c++, string, c++11

Why the following code have compilation error?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str="abc";

    string result=str[0];
    cout<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, the following code works fine:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str="abc";

    str=str[0];
    cout<<str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I works in unix and compilation command is: "g++ -g test.cpp -std=c++11 -o a", thenm ./a

The error for the first test.cpp after compile is:

```
test.cpp:9:21: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
  string result=str[0];
                     ^
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:490:7: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' [-fpermissive]
       basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc());
       ^
```

Comment: And the compilation error is ... ?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/75039/why-declare-a-variable-in-one-line-and-assign-to-it-in-the-next might give you some enlightment

Answer (score 3):

`std::basic_string` doesn't have [any constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes a single `CharT` argument. This means that `std::string` (i.e. `std::basic_string<char>`) cannot be constructed from a single `char`.

The class does, however, have an [assignment operator overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) that takes a single `CharT` argument, which is why your second example compiles.

The difference between the two cases is because in the first you're performing *copy initialization*, which means technically you're first attempting to construct a temporary `std::string` instance from the `char` argument, and then copy it over to `result`. In the second you're performing *assignment*, which means assigning a new value to an existing `std::string` instance.

---

`basic_string` does have a constructor that takes a count followed by a character:

```
basic_string(size_type count, CharT ch, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

so your original example would compile if you changed the offending line to

```
string result = {1, str[0]};
```

Comment: However, follow your logic, I tried the assignment overloading: #include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    { 
     string result='a';
     cout<<result<<endl;
     return 0;
    }      Still compilation error!!!

Comment: @user3259711 There is no assignment going on in that code. `string result='a';` is copy initialization; it's the same as your example that fails, except now you're using a literal.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine as well:

```
string result;
result=str[0];
```

That means the difference is between initialization and simple assignment and, if you examine the error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’
```

it should be clear that the initialization is not as "full-featured" as assignment - the is no `string` constructor that takes a `char` argument (there *is* an assignment that takes a `char` which is why your second example works).

You can fix it (in one way, there's no doubt others as well) by ensuring you initialize with a string rather than a character:

```
string result = str.substr(0,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

str[0] returns a char&, but there is no conversion from char& to std::string

try thins instead

```
string result = string(1, str[0]);
```